# Convergence of a series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{a_n}{n^p}\right)^\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've got a question about the convergence of a series during studying analysis.

If I know that a series of positive real numbers $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ converge, why does $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{a_n}{n^p}\right)^\frac{1}{2}$$ also converge for $p>1$?
Although I know about many convergence tests, I don't know how to apply those tests for this case. Since this problem is the form of "series A converge → series B converge", I've been thinking that it must be verified by using some "comparison" tests. Is this thinking correct?
All advice is welcome^_^
Thanks.

Comment: @Landscape : Yes. I missed it. I'll update now.

Comment: @Maesumi : But then, $\sum1$ does not converge which is not fulfilled the condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since
$$ab\leq a^2+b^2$$
we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{a_n}{n^p}\right)^\frac{1}{2}\leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^p} $$

Comment: @landscape Why you deleted your answer? As I have not deleted my answer *(and I do not do)* you must not remove yours, that's what you said.

Comment: Dear Sami Ben Romdhane, I deleted mine because I thought it was a little embarrassing that my answer posted later than yours, but shared the same idea with yours and contained less details than yours. If you don't mind, I will undelete it.

Comment: @Landscape A hint shouldn't contains more detail so I'd be happy if you undelete it.

Comment: I have undeleted my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Nice work, as usual!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** $$\left(\frac{a_n}{n^p}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\le\frac{1}{2}\left(a_n+\frac{1}{n^p}\right).$$

Comment: Wow. Really simple! How do you think this inequality... Thanks!

Comment: @Analysis: You are welcome. Since Sami Ben Romdhane posted a full answer a little earlier than me, let me delete my answer later.

Comment: @Analysis: I am sorry for being capricious. After some discussion with  Sami Ben Romdhane, I undeleted my answer.